# c# фильтрация Datagridview с помощью combobox

Tags: c#

есть datagridview привязанный к источнику данных , пытаюсь сделать фильтр по combobox. как сделать не понятно, помогите пожалуйста разобраться !ниже выложил код

```
 public IEnumerable<ProductModel> GetAllProduct()
    {
        ProductView viewfilter = new ProductView();
        var productList = new List<ProductModel>();
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = @"SELECT sklad.id, sklad.name, sklad.qty, sklad.price, category.name, company.name, sklad.date FROM sklad 
                                  LEFT JOIN category ON sklad.categoryID = category.id 
                                  LEFT JOIN company ON company.id = sklad.companyID";
            
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var productModel = new ProductModel();
                    productModel.ID = (int)reader[0];
                    productModel.Name = reader[1].ToString();
                    productModel.Qty = Convert.ToInt32(reader[2]);
                    productModel.Price = Convert.ToDouble(reader[3]);
                    productModel.Category = reader[4].ToString();
                    productModel.Company = reader[5].ToString();
                
                    productModel.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[6]);
                    productList.Add(productModel);
                   
                    var filterr = from product in productList where product.Category == viewfilter.comboBox2.Text.ToString() select product;
                }
                 
            }
        }
            return productList;
    }
```

combobox по которому нужно отфильтровать datagridview заполняется таким образом

```
    public IEnumerable<CategoryModel> GetCategoryComboboxValue()
    {
        var categoryList = new List<CategoryModel>();
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT category.id AS id, CONCAT(category.id, ' | ', category.name) as name FROM category";
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var categoryModel = new CategoryModel();
                    categoryModel.Id = (int)reader[0];
                    categoryModel.Name = reader[1].ToString();
                    categoryList.Add(categoryModel);
                }
            }
        }
        return categoryList;
    }
```

ProductModel:

```
        private int id;
    private string name;
    private int qty;
    private double price;
    private string categoryID;
    private string companyID;
    private DateTime date;


    // свойство поля (properties) VS проверки условия ввода данных (Validation или Валидация модели)

    [DisplayName("Product_ID")]

    public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    [DisplayName("Product_Name")]
    
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    [DisplayName("Product_Qty")]
    
    public int Qty
    {
        get { return qty; }
        set { qty = value; }
    }

    [DisplayName ("Product_price")]
    
    public double Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set { price = value; }
    }

    [DisplayName ("Product_Category")]
    
    public string Category   // categoryID заполняется данными combobox combobox заполняется из таблицы category
    {
        get { return categoryID; }
        set { categoryID = value; }
    }

    [DisplayName ("Product_Company")]
    [Required (ErrorMessage = "обязательно нужно выбирать название производителя товара")] // проверка выбора производителя товара

    public string Company
    {
        get {return companyID; }
        set { companyID = value; }
    }

    [DisplayName ("Date")]

     public DateTime Date
      {
          get { return date; }
          set { date = value; }
      }
```

CategoryModel

```
      public  class CategoryAddModel
{
    private int id;
    private string name;


    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }

    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас есть `var filterr = ...`. Далее пишете: `dataGridView.DataSource = filter.ToList();`. Не?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, метод лежит в отдельном классе,  тоесть view не видит этот метод напрямую, в форме как присвоит к датагриду  ` filter.ToList();` ?

Comment: Значит, вот это выражение `var filterr = ...` перенесите выше по коду. Применяйте его к значению, возвращаемому из `GetAllProduct`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov , тут еще такая проблема , таблица которая отображается в датагриде хранится ИД категорий, через join отображается название категорий. в комбобокс первый элемент ИД  категорий второй элемент название категорий, мне наверное нужно отсортировать по ИД категорий или это не имеет значение ?

Comment: Вся информация должна быть в вопросе. Комментарии сейчас вижу только я. А если отредактируете вопрос, то он снова появится на главной странице сайта в самом верху и его увидят все. И есть шанс, что кому-нибудь будет не лень вникнуть и помочь.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, в методе GetAllProduct() где запрос в базу указан какие значения  откуда берется. или вы не про это ? там связная таблица.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное так сортировка делается напрямую в гриде

````
    ```  bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = ВашаDataGrid.DataSource;

        if (ВашаDataGrid.DataSource != bs)
        {
            bs.Filter = string.Format("[product.Category] LIKE '%{0}%', comboBox2.Text);

            ВашаDataGrid.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        }
````

Либо делать SQL запрос к базе, фильтровать и выводить уже отфильтрованные данные

`SELECT product.name FROM product WHERE product.category" +comboBox2.Text`

и потом выводить уже в грид

Comment: пробовал через sql запрос не работает , хотя легче было бы через запрос в базу сразу вывести  отфильтрованный товар по combobox-y.

Comment: что можно будет сделать , не подскажете ?

Comment: @Mister junior
bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = ВашаDataGrid.DataSource;

        if (ВашаDataGrid.DataSource != bs)
        {
            bs.Filter = string.Format("[название столбца по которому сортируется] LIKE '%{0}%', comboBox2.Text);
}
Это должно было помочь в событие ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged мой код вставьте

Comment: у меня в форме datagridview таким образом заполняется                                                                     `public void SetProductListBindingSource(BindingSource productList)
        {
           dataGridViewShowProduct.DataSource = productList;
            
        }`

Comment: @ Евгений Нейфельд , вот ссылка на полный код формы и заполнения datagrdiview [https://dotnetfiddle.net/6fVfw6] , [https://dotnetfiddle.net/02eWq2] , помоги пожалуйста разобраться

Comment: @Mister junior ссылки пустые и я честно говоря сам еще тут плохо разбираюсь. Под winform несколько программ написал